# Are identical anonymous structures compatible?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, standards

Consider this code snippet:

```c
#include <threads.h>

int thread_start(void *ptr)
{
    struct {
        int a;
        int b;
    } *data = ptr;

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct {
        int a;
        int b;
    } data;

    thrd_t thread;
    thrd_create(&thread, thread_start, &data);
    thrd_join(thread, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Regarding the casting of a `void *` to `struct { int; int } *`, assuming that the fields of the anonymous structure are identical to the fields of the structure that was initially allocated, is this well defined behavior according to the C standard?

Comment: I would imagine so but can't find an explicit reference in the Standard. Others may well do better than I have done, though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compatible types and structures in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904668/compatible-types-and-structures-in-c) It appears that they aren't.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think that suggests that they aren't compatible terms of direct assignment. However, casting and re-casting *via* a `void*` is a bit of a different case. After all, they both *must* have the same aliasing/alignment requirements, etc.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that two structures are equivalent if and only if they are exactly the same character by character. Don't remember if it was only for tagged or for all (including anonymous) structures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These structs would be compatible if they were not in the same file.

Had `thread_start` been defined in a separately compiled .c file (i.e. a separate *translation unit*) then they would be compatible.  Specifically, the names, types, and order of the members are the same, and they both have the same tag which in this case is no tag.

Section [§6.2.7 ¶1](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p1) of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) lays out these requirements:

> Two  types   have *compatible  type* if  their  types  are  the  same.
> Additional  rules  for determining  whether  two types  are
> compatible  are  described  in  6.7.2  for  type  specifiers, in
> 6.7.3  for  type  qualifiers,  and  in  6.7.6  for  declarators. **Moreover,  two  structure, union,  or  enumerated  types  declared  *in
> separate  translation  units*  are  compatible  if  their tags  and
> members  satisfy  the  following  requirements:  If  one  is  declared
> with  a  tag,  the other  shall  be  declared  with  the  same  tag.
> If  both  are  completed  anywhere  within  their respective
> translation units, then the following additional requirements apply:
> there shall be   a   one-to-one   correspondence   between   their
> members   such   that   each   pair   of corresponding members are
> declared with compatible types; if one member of the pair is declared
> with  an  alignment  specifier, the  other  is  declared  with  an
> equivalent  alignment specifier;  and  if  one  member  of  the  pair
> is  declared  with  a  name,  the  other  is  declared with the same
> name.**  For two structures, corresponding members shall be declared in
> the same  order.   For  two  structures  or  unions,  corresponding
> bit-fields  shall  have  the  same widths.  For two enumerations,
> corresponding members shall have the same values.

So these structs *would* be compatible if they were not in the same file.  But because they are, the structs are not compatible.

[§6.7.2.1 ¶8](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p8) says:

> The presence of a struct-declaration-list in a struct-or-union-specifier declares a new type, within a translation unit.

So, §6.7.2.1 specifies what happens in a single translation unit. The specification in §6.2.7 overrides the specification in §6.7.2.1 when the declarations are in separate translation units.

<sup>*NB: It's easy to confuse 6.2.7 and 6.7.2.*</sup>

Comment: Where, in what you have quoted, does it *explicitly* preclude structures defined in the same translation unit? One could argue that the mention of "separate" units is just for clarity over those in the same.

Comment: Maybe this (and the suggested dupe) need the Language Lawyer tag: *absence of evidence is not evidence of absence?*

Comment: @AdrianMole Wouldn't the part "*declared in separate translation units*" be completely redundant if it wasn't to differentiate between two cases?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Maybe. I'm not a C Language-Lawyer. But, one *could* read it as: "**even if** declared in separate translation units." Just sayin'.

Comment: @AdrianMole — No; the words 'even if' cannot be inferred from the definitional language "two structure, union or enumerated types declared in separate translation units".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah - I can actually see that. However, why would the rule be more restrictive for stuff in the same unit, over stuffs separated?

Comment: It kind of begs the question that if the two identical anonymous struct types are defined in translation unit "a", and another identical anonymous struct type is defined in translation unit "b", which one in "a" is compatible with the one in "b"?

Comment: @IanAbbott Wow. Looks like a can of worms to me. Unless these are not compatible even if declared in different TUs.

Comment: @AdrianMole: this is overriding (relaxing) a restriction elsewhere.  C11 [§6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers ¶8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p8) says: _The presence of a struct-declaration-list in a struct-or-union-specifier declares a new type, within a translation unit._  It means that you can't define a structure type inside one function and use it in any other function in the same TU, even if spelled identically.  You must define the structure type at file scope if the type is used in more than one function.

Comment: @IanAbbott: The types with local (function) scope in each TU have local scope and cannot be accessed outside that scope.  The cross-TU stuff only works when the types are defined at file scope.

Comment: We *definitely* need `language-lawyer` here, then.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler But two identical anonymous structs can be defined in the file scope in the same TU

Comment: @EugeneSh. I guess the way out of that can of worms is that ultimately it is objects that are being compared for type compatibility. So `struct { int a; int b; } foo;` in translation unit "a" would be compatible with `extern struct { int a; int b; } foo;` in translation unit "b", but neither is compatible with `struct {int a; int b; } bar;`. And also, `typedef struct { int a; int b } tfoo;` in translation unit "a" would be compatible with the identical type definition in translation unit "b".

Comment: @EugeneSh. — hmmm, yes.  Ugh!  Fortunately, only those with too much time on their hands would spend much time worrying about such a problem.  Can you devise an example where it would matter?  At file scope in TU-1: `struct { … } a; struct { … } b;` — in TU-2: `extern struct { … } a; extern struct { … } b;` — that doesn't do it, but I suspect there's something along those lines.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, IanAbbott Good point. I can't come up with even a nonsensical use-case. Maybe someone else can..

Comment: @IanAbbott: Re “which one in "a" is compatible with the one in "b"?”: Each structure type in “a” is compatible with the structure type in “b”. At the same time, neither structure type in “a” is compatible with the other; “compatible” is not required to be a transitive relationship.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: What sort of use case are you looking for? I expect the rules here arise out of practical realities. Given a header containing `typedef struct { float x, y; } Point;` included in multiple translation units, we want `Point` to be the “same” type, hence a compatible type, in those translation units. Thus justifies the cross-unit rule. At the same time, if `typedef struct { float re, im; } Complex;` is declared in one unit, there is a benefit to treating it as a different and incompatible type from `Point` and reporting errors if code attempts an assignment of one to the other…

Comment: … Of course it would be a further benefit if `Point` and `Complex` could be distinguished across units, but the limitations of existing object module formats precluded that when the rules about this in the C standard were being written.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Adding `typedef` completely changes the problem(s).  It is effectively irrelevant to the question.  Or, put another way, any use case of interest would not include any use of `typedef`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Again: What sort of a use case are you looking for? The `typedef` use case explains why the rules are the way they are. I did not say it is the problem in the question; I gave it as a use case that explains the rules.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Agreed.  We still have an anonymous struct, it just also happens to have an alias.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I know `typedef` completely changes things; I said so.  The question I raised is whether someone can give an example which uses two or more `struct /*no tag*/ { /* details */ }` in two separate translation units (TU-1 and TU-2) and they can cause confusion as to which type in TU-1 is referenced in TU-2, as asked by Ian Abbott.  To be clear: there is no `typedef`; to be significant (usable), there must be either a structure tag, which I've said is not present, or a list of variables (otherwise the declaration is pointless); the details must be the same too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `typedef` is not completely different if you think of any invocation of a storage class specifier or a default storage class on an anonymous struct type as pinning down that type. (`typedef` is treated as a storage class specifier after all, syntactically.)